# SQL reduce post date and time by 8 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how to write and run a SQL query to reduce 8 hours from the published time of all posts in a table please.

I need it to also properly change the date, not just the time please.

I will run it via phpMyAdmin.

- Table name: my_posts
- Column name: Posted
- Column example current value: 2020-12-11 02:00:00
- Column example after change value: 2020-12-10 18:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the time using `interval` arithmetic:

```
update my_posts
    set posted = posted - interval 8 hour;
```